# Javascript get Class of a parsed json string

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a json string, whick i parsed with `JSON.parse(String);`
My problem is I want to check which class it extends (It extends from my custom class Action) but I don't know how to check it with code:

`action instanceOf Action => false
typeOf Action => Object`

Comment: once you json.parse it completes creates new object

Comment: It won't extend any class. JSON only supports plain objects, plain arrays, and primitives.

Comment: and how can I check from which class this object is?

Comment: @Fridious When you convert an object to JSON, class information is discarded, so it's not possible.

Answer (score -1):

The question for classes is not a hundred percent correct in JavaScript. It is prototype based. But back to your question: results from `JSON.parse()` are always either `string`, `number` or (potentially nested) `Array` or `Object`. You can read more about JSON here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Ok, but is there a other way to get the class? Because my problem is I receive with websockets json strings and these are classes in javascript and I don't know how to sort it for each class.

Comment: @Fridious You need to pass the class information as additional data.

Comment: you mean I have to save the class in an extra field?

Comment: You can't really save a class to a girl if it is serialized as JSON. But you can add additional data to the JSON that tell the other side what type it is. Then you have to parse that data on the receivers side and construct a new class instance of the given type and fill it with the actual data. But this is manual work you have to do. You can't use any `instanceof` or `typeof` statements since the data does not contain any information needed for these checks. You should learn a little more about JSON and how serialized data works.